# how can I arrange this image with 10px padding right side?

Tags: html, css, web

```
.password{
    padding: 10px 10px 9px 15px;
    align-items: center;
    background: url('/assets/images/View_hide.png') no-repeat right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]how can I add right-padding to the password icon so that it can have some place left at the end

Comment: Padding only works for content inside element, not for background

Comment: Check out the `background-origin` property.